# How Do I create Dynamic Security Groups in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-accounts, azure-ad

Currently I have users synced from our on premise AD synced to the cloud so I have users in groups (departments) and then I have created a all staff group using the security groups pushed up.

I was wondering are the groups dynamic or are they fixed? Our connector syncs up daily but will the all staff group be automatically updated also?

Comment: you mean you import the AD group into the SharePoint and wondering if it is dynamic? i.e adding more users in AD group, should reach to sharepoin?

Comment: Not really clear what you asking?